# CPLEX C API retrieve variables type

Tags: c, cplex

Is it possible (using the CPLEX C APIs) to retrieve the variables type (CPX_CONTINUOUS, CPX_BINARY, CPX_INTEGER, ...)  of a model not handled by me but directly built from an .mps file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [CPXgetctype](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/getctype.html) function. Here's the example given in the documentation link:

```
 status = CPXgetctype (env, lp, ctype, 0, cur_numcols-1);
```

To get the number of columns use [CPXgetnumcols](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/getnumcols.html).